# convertir archivo .txt a arreglo bidimensional con python

Tags: python, array, matrices

Tengo un archivo `.txt` con mucha información, quiero leerlo con python pero a la vez que lo leo necesito ir llenando un arreglo bidimensional tomando la palabra o el dato separado por la coma como una posición y no cada caracter como una posición. Cada dato separado por coma corresponde a un tipo de dato distinto. La información en el archivo esta ordenada algo así:

```
"600900", "", "GROUP", 1, 0, 0, 4, "", 0:00, 0:00, 09JAN, 09JAN, 09JAN, 09JAN, false, 0,
```

En mi archivo txt tengo demasiada información igual separada por filas y cada fila contiene 16 columnas en total. Lo que necesito debería lucir algo así:

```
[600900][ ][GROUP][1][0][0][4][ ][0:00][0:00][09JAN][09JAN][09JAN][09JAN][false][0]
[600800][ ][GROUP][1][0][0][4][ ][0:00][0:00][09JAN][09JAN][09JAN][09JAN][false][0]
[600700][ ][GROUP][1][0][0][4][ ][0:00][0:00][09JAN][09JAN][09JAN][09JAN][false][0]
```

Mi código **Python**

```
file=open('escrito.txt','r') 
data=file.readlines() 
file.close() 
print (data)
```

Solo lee e imprime la información del archivo

Comment: Y el código en python??

Comment: Solo tengo el de leer el archivo

file=open('escrito.txt','r')
data=file.readlines()
file.close()
print (data)

Comment: Para añadir información relevante a la pregunta, por favor edítala y añade tu código, logs de error y demás datos que le sirvan a quienes intentamos ayudar. Gracias!

Comment: Hola Rafael, bienvenido a [es.so]. La solución directa pasa por aplicar [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) a cada línea. ¿Te has mirado el módulo [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)? Te facilitaría la tarea de parsear el archivo. Si no es una tarea o algo por el estilo considera usar NumPy o Pandas, cargar el csv con [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)  es simple y si vas a operar con los datos mucho más eficiente que usar listas anidadas de Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para la versión de Python 2 puede utilizar el módulo `csv` para archivos de texto cuyo delimitador se una `,`. Puede hacer una lectura de la siguiente forma

```
import csv

with open('datos.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    rows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in rows:
            print ', '.join(row)
```

Este ejemplo lo que hace basicamente es una impresión de cada fila, para su caso en vez del `print` puede crear la lógica que le construya lo que necesita. Puede tener una mayor referencia revisando la [Documentación oficial del módulo CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) para Python 2